# React Three Fiber Canvas causes all components to not render when rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to learn and work with react and threejs specifically react-three/fiber. I'm running react and three 18.2 and @react-three/fiber 8.11.5. The scene renders fine as long as there is no  tag being rendered at all. Regardless of whether it's in the same component or not or whether there it is populated by a mesh or any settings. I am getting no errors and it saves perfectly fine, other than the fact that it doesn't render when there is a  tag.

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />,
  </React.StrictMode>
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. Learn more: 
reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
import Box from './Components/Box';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <p>
          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <a
          className="App-link"
          href="https://reactjs.org"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Learn React
        </a>
      </header>
      <Canvas>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App.css

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #282c34;
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
  color: white;
}

.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

I've tried reverting back to React 17, but have had issues with getting the right version of three. I've tried different ways of implementing  such as having that be the root. That makes it impossible to render anything at all. I've tried rendering the canvas directly in index.js, no dice. I've gotten working code on code sandbox, only for it to not work in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I had to install all of the dependencies directly in my workspace. After opening a terminal in the root folder of my project (Where I run npm start) and npm installing everything it worked fine.